# HTML5 localStorage redirect based on value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to redirect the user to another page based on a value held in HTML5 localStorage.

```
var user=localStorage.getItem('uname');
if(user==""||user==null)
{
    window.location='secure.html';
}
```

This redirects even when `localStorage` has supposedly been cleared.

Is there any way to check what is held in `localStorage`. I have used alerts which show 'null' but the redirect still happens.

Comment: You should use strict comparison `if (user === "" || !user)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `localStorage` is cleared, `localStorage.getItem('uname')` will be `null`. If you don't want to redirect when it's cleared, remove this condition for redirection. If you want to redirect only when it's empty string, do this:

if (localStorage.getItem('uname') === "")
  {
    window.location='secure.html';
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the length of the object is 0 instead

```
var user=localStorage.getItem('uname');
if(user.length == 0)
{
   window.location='secure.html';
}
```

But, if you are going to redirect the user if the "uname" is not null:

```
var user=localStorage.getItem('uname');
if(user.length != 0)
{
   window.location='secure.html';
}
```

Comment: This gives an error `user is null`. Even `if(user.length==0||user==null){}` brings up the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be confusion between `user==""||user==null`

```
var user=localStorage.getItem('uname');
if(user==null)
{
    window.location='secure.html';
}
```

so far seems to be working